# asio: co_await multiple outsourced async tasks

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

I have a single threaded io_context, which serves as an event loop. I also have multiple heavy tasks, which must not block the main event_loop, but should also run massively in parallel.

All tasks in the main loop are `asio::awaitables<void>`. Those tasks can create arbitrary new awaitable tasks or spawn them into the io_context's executioner (`asio::co_spawn`).

The concurrent tasks are posted to a thread_pool, but they do not start as soon the awaitables are created, they start at the moment I try to await them.
This is extremely annoying, especially, when the creating coroutine want's to create and spawn more concurrent tasks to await them later as needed.

How do I get those tasks started, as soon the awaitables are created?

Here's some minimal example code which shows the problem:

```
#define ASIO_STANDALONE 1
#define ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT 1
#define ASIO_HAS_STD_COROUTINE 1
//

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <asio/bind_cancellation_slot.hpp>
#include <asio/cancellation_signal.hpp>
#include <asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <asio/post.hpp>
#include <asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <asio/thread_pool.hpp>

using namespace std;

auto my_async(auto& context, auto&& func, auto&& handler) {
    return async_initiate<decltype(handler), void(std::error_code e)>(
        [&context](auto&& handler, auto&& func) {
            asio::post(context, [func = std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)]() { func(); });
        },
        handler, std::forward<decltype(func)>(func));
}

auto main() -> int {
    std::cout << "start program\n";

    asio::thread_pool pool(4);
    asio::io_service io_service{};
    std::thread jthrd{};
    asio::executor_work_guard<asio::io_context::executor_type> guard{io_service.get_executor()};
    jthrd = std::thread{[&io_service]() {
        std::cout << "start loop\n";
        io_service.run();
    }};

    asio::steady_timer timer{asio::system_executor{}, asio::steady_timer::duration::max()};

    asio::cancellation_signal signal;
    auto cancel = signal.slot();

    auto expansive_task_generator = [&](std::string coroname) {
        return [&, coroname = std::move(coroname)] {
            std::cout << "begin : " << coroname << " with tid: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
            auto timer = asio::steady_timer(io_service);
            timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(10));
            timer.wait();
            std::cout << "10s timer expired" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "end : " << coroname << " with tid: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        };
    };

    auto mainloop_awaitable = [&]() -> asio::awaitable<void> {
        std::cout << "run mainloop event\n";
        auto awaitable1 = my_async(pool, expansive_task_generator("aw1"), asio::use_awaitable);
        auto awaitable2 = my_async(pool, expansive_task_generator("aw2"), asio::use_awaitable);
        // < possible medium expansive work here>
        auto awaitable3 = my_async(pool, expansive_task_generator("aw3"), asio::use_awaitable);
        auto awaitable4 = my_async(
            pool, [&timer]() { timer.expires_at(asio::steady_timer::time_point::min()); }, asio::use_awaitable);

        auto timer = asio::steady_timer(io_service);
        timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(10));
        co_await timer.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable);

        std::cout << "before co_await\n";    // My expectation: tasks are running already
        co_await std::move(awaitable1);      // Problem: These are all executed serially
        // < possible medium expansive work here>
        co_await std::move(awaitable2);    // Problem: These are all executed serially
        co_await std::move(awaitable3);    // Problem: These are all executed serially
        // < possible medium expansive work here>
        co_await std::move(awaitable4);    // Problem: These are all executed serially
        co_await timer.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable);
    };

    auto mainloop_completion = [](std::exception_ptr e) {
        if (e) {
            try {
                std::rethrow_exception(e);
            } catch (const std::exception& e) {
                std::cerr << "mainloop failed with: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            } catch (...) {
                std::cerr << "mainloop failed with unknown exception" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    };

    asio::co_spawn(io_service.get_executor(), std::move(mainloop_awaitable),
                   asio::bind_cancellation_slot(cancel, mainloop_completion));
    guard.reset();
    jthrd.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Another good alternative, would be some sort of `asio::future::async_wait(asio::use_awaitable)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::cout << "before co_await" << std::endl; // My expectation: tasks are running already
```

`awaitable<>`s do not commence until `co_await`-ed.

> *According to the changelog `experimental::use_promise` [allows eager execution and synchronisation of async operations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#:%7E:text=allows%20eager%20execution%20and%20synchronisation%20of%20async%20operations) but I haven't worked with it yet.*

I see a number of issues with `my_async`:

```
auto my_async(auto& context, auto&& func, auto&& handler) {
    return async_initiate<decltype(handler), void(std::error_code e)>(
        [&context](auto&& handler, auto&& func) {
            asio::post(context, [func = std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)]() { func(); });
        },
        handler, std::forward<decltype(func)>(func));
}
```

- it never executes the handler of the completion token
- it passes an execution context by reference, where executors are more generic and idiomatic
- soft concern: I wonder what the purpose, considering that it doesn't seem to do more than `post`

Reading through the rest I spot

- strangely the code uses most modern features, but then uses the deprecated `io_service` type
- the code mixes execution context without a clear goal (especially the timer being on `system_executor` is mystifying to me)
- the cancellation slot isn't actually used
- there are multiple `timer` variables shadowing the one in main. Some of them aren't actually, others are used exclusively synchronously, so I'd replace

  ```
   auto timer = asio::steady_timer(io_service);
   timer.expires_from_now(10s);
   timer.wait();
  ```

  by

  ```
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
  ```

  Note also, one is initialized with `duration::max()`, but reset to `time_point::min()` - those are inconsistent and might lead to subtle bugs depending on comparisons used.

### Waiting For Set Of Awaitables

You can use `parallel_group` (see [`make_parallel_group`](https://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_24_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/experimental__make_parallel_group.html)) or use the awaitable operators to do it for you:

```
 asio::steady_timer local_timer(io_service, 5s);
 auto delay = local_timer.async_wait(use_awaitable);

 trace("before co_await");
 co_await (std::move(delay) && std::move(aw1) && std::move(aw2) && std::move(aw3) && std::move(aw4));
 trace("after co_await");
```

One benefit of using `make_parallel_group` manually might be that [it allows range-construction](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#:%7E:text=Add%20range%2Dbased%20experimental%3A%3Amake_parallel_group()%20overloads)

### Demonstrating

Addressing most of the above concerns, and adding interesting timings and tracing of them:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1b3222a2d208112)**

```
//#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING 1
//#define BOOST_ASIO_STANDALONE        1
//#define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT      1
//#define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_COROUTINE 1

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

auto my_async(auto executor, auto task, auto&& token) {
    return async_initiate<decltype(token), void(std::error_code e)>(
        [executor](auto handler, auto task) {
            asio::post( //
                executor, [h = std::move(handler), t = std::move(task)]() mutable {
                    t();
                    std::move(h)(std::error_code{});
                });
        },
        std::forward<decltype(token)>(token), std::move(task));
}

static std::atomic_int thread_counter = 0;

thread_local int const t_id  = thread_counter++;
static auto const      now   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
static auto const      start = now();

static void trace(auto const&... args) {
    static std::mutex mx;

    std::lock_guard lk(mx);
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms t_id:" << t_id << " ";
    (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
}

int main()  {
    trace("start program");

    asio::thread_pool pool(4);
    asio::io_context  io_service{};

    auto guard = make_work_guard(io_service);

    std::thread thrd = std::thread{[&io_service]() {
        trace("start io_service loop");
        io_service.run();
        trace("end io_service loop");
    }};

    asio::steady_timer main_timer{io_service, asio::steady_timer::time_point::max()};

    asio::cancellation_signal cancel;

    auto make_task = [&](std::string name, auto cost) { // generates expensive tasks
        return [=] {
            trace(name, " begin ", cost/1.s, "s work");
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(cost);
            trace(name, " end ", cost/1.s, "s work");
        };
    };

    using asio::use_awaitable;
    using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;

    auto mainloop = [&]() -> asio::awaitable<void> {
        trace("run mainloop event");
        auto ex  = pool.get_executor();
        auto aw1 = my_async(ex, make_task("aw1", 6s), use_awaitable);
        auto aw2 = my_async(ex, make_task("aw2", 2s), use_awaitable);
        // < possible medium expansive work here>
        auto aw3 = my_async(ex, make_task("aw3", 4s), use_awaitable);
        auto aw4 = my_async(
            ex,
            [&main_timer]() {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
                trace("aw4 cancels main_timer");
                main_timer.expires_at(asio::steady_timer::time_point::min());
            },
            use_awaitable);

        asio::steady_timer local_timer(io_service, 5s);
        auto delay = local_timer.async_wait(use_awaitable);

        trace("before co_await");
        co_await (std::move(delay) && std::move(aw1) && std::move(aw2) && std::move(aw3) && std::move(aw4));
        trace("after co_await");
    };

    trace(std::boolalpha, "main_timer.expiry() == max()? ",
          main_timer.expiry() == std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max());

    asio::co_spawn(io_service.get_executor(), mainloop(), [&](std::exception_ptr e) {
        if (e) {
            try {
                std::rethrow_exception(e);
            } catch (const std::exception& e) {
                trace("mainloop failed with: ", e.what());
            } catch (...) {
                trace("mainloop failed with unknown exception");
            }
        }

        trace(std::boolalpha, "main_timer.expiry() == min()? ",
              main_timer.expiry() == std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::min());
    });

    guard.reset();
    thrd.join();
    trace("bye");
}
```

Example output:

```
     0ms t_id:0 start program
     0ms t_id:0 main_timer.expiry() == max()? true
     0ms t_id:1 start io_service loop
     0ms t_id:1 run mainloop event
     0ms t_id:1 before co_await
     0ms t_id:2 aw1 begin 6s work
     0ms t_id:3 aw2 begin 2s work
     1ms t_id:4 aw3 begin 4s work
  2001ms t_id:3 aw2 end 2s work
  3001ms t_id:5 aw4 cancels main_timer
  4001ms t_id:4 aw3 end 4s work
  6001ms t_id:2 aw1 end 6s work
  6001ms t_id:1 after co_await
  6001ms t_id:1 main_timer.expiry() == min()? true
  6001ms t_id:1 end io_service loop
  6001ms t_id:0 bye
```

The corresponding handler tracking visualization:

[image]

### More/Simpler?

From the presence of the cancellation slot and the `main_timer` I get the impression you might have wanted global deadline semantics. I'd write it like so: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e80581a7d26c279a

```
//#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING 1
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using asio::use_awaitable;
using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;

static std::atomic_int thread_id_gen = 0;
thread_local int const t_id  = thread_id_gen++;
static auto const      now   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
static auto const      start = now();

static void trace(auto const&... args) {
    static std::mutex mx;
    std::lock_guard lk(mx);
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms t_id:" << t_id << " ";
    (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
}

auto my_async(auto ex, auto task, auto&& token) {
    return async_initiate<decltype(token), void(std::string)>(
        [ex, work = make_work_guard(ex)](auto handler, auto task) {
            asio::post( //
                ex,
                [h = std::move(handler), t = std::move(task)]() mutable //
                { std::move(h)(t()); });
        },
        std::forward<decltype(token)>(token), std::move(task));
}

auto task(std::string name, auto cost) { // expensive task
    return [=]() -> std::string {
        trace(name, " begin ", cost / 1.s, "s work");
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(cost); // NOTE: anti-pattern to block in async task!
        trace(name, " end ", cost / 1.s, "s work");
        return name + " returned value";
    };
}

asio::awaitable<void> mainloop(auto pool) {
    trace("run mainloop event");
    auto aw1 = my_async(pool, task("aw1", 6s), use_awaitable);
    auto aw2 = my_async(pool, task("aw2", 2s), use_awaitable);
    auto aw3 = my_async(pool, task("aw3", 4s), use_awaitable);

    asio::steady_timer local_timer(pool, 5s);
    auto delay = local_timer.async_wait(use_awaitable);

    trace("before co_await");
    auto x = co_await (std::move(delay) && std::move(aw1) && std::move(aw2) && std::move(aw3));
    trace(get<0>(x));
    trace(get<1>(x));
    trace(get<2>(x));
    trace("after co_await");
};

asio::awaitable<void> deadline(auto expiry) {
    co_await asio::steady_timer(co_await asio::this_coro::executor, expiry).async_wait(use_awaitable);
    trace("deadline expired");
}

int main()  {
    asio::thread_pool pool(10);
    asio::io_context ioc;
    trace("start program");

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    asio::co_spawn(ioc, /*deadline(3s) || */ mainloop(pool.get_executor()),
                   redirect_error(asio::detached, ec));

    ioc.run();
    trace("mainloop completed (", ec.message(), ")");

    pool.join();
    trace("work pool joined");
}
```

Prints e.g.:

```
     0ms t_id:0 start program
     0ms t_id:0 run mainloop event
     0ms t_id:0 before co_await
     0ms t_id:1 aw1 begin 6s work
     0ms t_id:2 aw3 begin 4s work
     0ms t_id:3 aw2 begin 2s work
  2001ms t_id:3 aw2 end 2s work
  4000ms t_id:2 aw3 end 4s work
  6000ms t_id:1 aw1 end 6s work
  6001ms t_id:0 aw1 returned value
  6001ms t_id:0 aw2 returned value
  6001ms t_id:0 aw3 returned value
  6001ms t_id:0 after co_await
  6001ms t_id:0 mainloop completed (Success)
  6001ms t_id:0 work pool joined
```

Uncommenting the deadline like:

```
asio::co_spawn(ioc, deadline(3s) || mainloop(pool.get_executor()),
               redirect_error(asio::detached, ec));
```

Prints [e.g.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c29b313c93b11611)

```
     0ms t_id:0 start program
     0ms t_id:0 run mainloop event
     0ms t_id:0 before co_await
     0ms t_id:1 aw1 begin 6s work
     0ms t_id:2 aw2 begin 2s work
     0ms t_id:3 aw3 begin 4s work
  2001ms t_id:2 aw2 end 2s work
  3000ms t_id:0 deadline expired
  4001ms t_id:3 aw3 end 4s work
  6000ms t_id:1 aw1 end 6s work
  6001ms t_id:0 mainloop completed (Success)
  6001ms t_id:0 work pool joined
```

To get a bit more accurate feedback on the completion:

```
asio::co_spawn(ioc, mainloop(pool.get_executor()) || deadline(3s), [](std::exception_ptr e, auto r) {
    if (!e)
        trace("mainloop ", 0 == r.index() ? "completed" : "timed out");
    else
        try {
            std::rethrow_exception(e);
        } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
            trace("mainloop error (", se.code().message(), ")");
        }
});
```

Prints

```
  ....
  6001ms t_id:0 mainloop timed out
  6001ms t_id:0 work pool joined
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for that detailed answer. I think after you mentioned it, that experimental::promise, in combination with `make_parallel_group` is what I am searching for. Those timers should only "simulate" costly work.